# Does Visual Studio 2010 create backup files?

Tags: visual-studio, crash, backup

Just got a random bsod on my machine and Form1.cs is suddenly empty, any way to restore the code? thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files\` (or the equivalent on your system).

Files will be placed there if auto-recover is enabled, which I believe it is by default.  If you want to check that feature is enabled, follow the steps here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/30/autorecover-vstipenv0019.aspx

Another top tip is to set 'Save all changes' before building. That setting is in Options, under Projects and Solutions / Build and Run.

Comment: The folder is empty, the bsod occured when I started the compiling process.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I updated answer with another setting that may help prevent this next time.

Comment: Thanks, back to rewriting it. :)