# How to autobackup Visual Studio Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash, backup

Is there a Add-In or a non default setting to automaticly backup your source files in Visual Studio?

I ask this, because my PC crashed into a BSOD whilst stopping debugging of a Project which used the Ping class. (Bug was reported 4 years ago to ms...) And my main file was filled with `nul`s (as n++ showed).

So I looked into the myDocuments (as suggested [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900743/does-visual-studio-2010-create-backup-files)) folder just to find nothing, and yes the setting is enabled. So now I have to use a 2 hour old file which gdrive gave me.

My idea of such a backup mechanism would be that like every five minutes changed files will be backuped into a custom directory. Those backups should remain until the backup files get too old or too much storage is used.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community edition on Win 7x64.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some sort of hosted source control for backing up your work, something like like GitHub or Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Thought of that. Currently I'm using VisualSVN which i'm using for an offline SVN control. Only thing I'm missing there is the automatic aspect. Right now I have to manually commit changes, which is easy to forget for me... (Guess it's the same with GitHub) And I don't want to use VS Online cause I like to keep my IDE offline...